# WPF: How to data bind an object to an element and apply a data template through code?

Tags: wpf, binding, code-behind

I have created a class `LeagueMatch`.

```
public class LeagueMatch
{
    public string Home
    {
        get { return home; }
        set { home = value; }
    }

    public string Visitor
    {
        get { return visitor; }
        set { visitor = value; }
    }

    private string home;
    private string visitor;

    public LeagueMatch()
    {
    }
}
```

Next, I have defined a datatemplate resource for `LeagueMatch` objects in XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MatchTemplate" DataType="{x:Type entities:LeagueMatch}">
    <Grid Name="MatchGrid" Width="140" Height="50" Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Home}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="- vs -" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Visitor}" />
    </Grid>    
</DataTemplate>
```

In the XAML code-behind, I want to create a `ContentPresenter` object and to set it's data binding to a previously initialized `LeagueMatch` object and apply the defined data template. How is that supposed to be done? Thanks.

### Solution

```
LeagueMatch match = new LeagueMatch("A team", "B team");

ContentPresenter contentPresenter = new ContentPresenter();
contentPresenter.ContentTemplate = this.FindResource("MatchTemplate") as DataTemplate;
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = match;
contentPresenter.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, binding);

matchSlot.Children.Clear();
matchSlot.Children.Add(contentPresenter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource yourTemplate}" 
                   DataContext="{Binding Match}"/>
```

In code-behind:

```
ContentPresenter c = new ContentPresenter();
c.ContentTemplate = FindResource("yourTemplate");
Binding b = new Binding();
b.Path = "Match"; // if the object is a property on someObject, otherwise leave it out.
b.Source = someObject;

c.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, b);
```

Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
public class Sample : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string sampleField = "";

  public string SampleProperty
  {
    get { return sampleField; }
    set
    {
       sampleField = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged("SampleProperty");
    }
  }

  #region INotifyPropertyChanged

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
  {
     var handler = PropertyChanged;
     if(handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
  }
}
```

Be sure to change your properties **only** by assigning to the property so the event gets executed. The binding engine is listening to those events to refresh the binding.

Comment: Data template works now, but the data from the object are not showing up in the content presenter. There's one thing I don't understand: When you created a `Binding` object, what is the string `"Match"` supposed to represent? I have implemented everything you've written, except that string in the binding constructor. Thanks.

Comment: made it more explicit - the constructor parameter is the path.

Comment: It doesn't work on my side; the data binded object values are not showing in the content presenter. I have a method in which I create the `LeagueMatch` object and the `ContentPresenter` object. I have updated my question with that method. Do you have an idea why the Home and Visitor strings are not showing up perhaps? Thanks.

Comment: Try implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your class.

Comment: I've implemented it by following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx, but nothing's changed in the outcome.

Comment: Are you adding the `ContentPresenter` to your visual tree? If I remember correctly, data binding only works if the object is under control of the wpf engine.

Comment: Yes, in my WPF class I have defined a `DockPanel` which is a placeholder for content presenter which is set as dock panel's child. The content presenter is dynamically created and added to the dock panel through the method given in the question update.

Comment: John Bowen found a little glitch in your code, explained in his answer to the question. Now it all works. Please, edit you answer with the correction and I'll accept it as final answer to the question. Thanks for all the help, I appreciate it.

Comment: changed it. I just went by intuition and msdn, so I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind to the Content property on the ContentPresenter, not DataContext, to apply the template to your data:

```
contentPresenter.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, binding);
```

Comment: I'll make Femaref's answer accepted once he makes the editing in his code. This way, the whole implementation will be in one place. Thank you once again for spotting the error.